# CakePHP doesn't save correct data in case of an HABTM

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, orm, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to save some data using HasAndBelongsToMany relations.
Here are my tables :

**commercials:**

- id (int) AI
- name (varchar)

**showrooms:**

- id (int) AI
- name (varchar)

**commercials_showrooms:**

- id (int) AI
- commercial_id (int)
- showroom_id (int)

And my models :

```
class Showroom extends AppModel
{
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Commercial',
    );
}

class Commercial extends AppModel
{
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Showroom'
    );
}
```

I'm trying to save data (hard coded for now) this way :

```
 $this->loadModel('Showroom');
 $this->Showroom->saveAll(array(
             'Showroom' => array(
                 'id' => 1
             ),
             'Commercial' => array(
                 'name' => 'test'
             )
         ));
```

saveAll() returns (bool)true, however, nothing is saved in database.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: try saving `array(array(
             'Showroom' => array(
                 'id' => 1
             ),
             'Commercial' => array(
                 'name' => 'test'
             )
         ))`. Also, what is your cake version? And: do you get validation errors (did you tried just validating before saving)?

Comment: I did try, this does not work.
I'm using CakePHP 2.4.1
There is no validation for models I'm trying to save.

Comment: the way that you are testing it also is incorrect.

Comment: Can you be more precise please ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the section on ["Saving Related Model Data (HABTM)" in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm)?

It suggests a different format than you're using for your data.

Comment: I see no differences.

Comment: The difference is the extra surrounding array, like the one I said you should try. But you said that didn't work either. Did it give you different errors at least?

Comment: @dynamic_cast: Don't just use the first example you see - Read the part that says "You can also use this format to save several records and their HABTM associations with saveAll()..."

Comment: As @Nunser said it did not work neither. And the problem did not change at all, nothing is changed in datatabase.

Answer (score 0):

to test your table if is working try this in your controller:

```
$this->loadModel('CommercialsShowroom');

$CommercialsShowroom = array('CommercialsShowroom'=>array(
                                                          'commercial_id'=>your_value,
                                                          'showroom_id'=>your_value));
$this->CommercialsShowroom->create();
if ($this->CommercialsShowroom->save($CommercialsShowroom, false)){
    var_dump('It is saved');
}
```

and for Model configuration read Dave link for more information

```
//CommercialsShowroom model:

        var $belongsTo = array(
        'Commercial' => array(
            'className' => 'Commercial',
            'foreignKey' => 'commercial_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Showroom' => array(
            'className' => 'Showroom',
            'foreignKey' => 'showroom_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

//Showroom model:

     var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Commercial' => array(
            'className' => 'Commercial',
            'joinTable' => 'commercials_showrooms',
            'foreignKey' => 'commercial_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'showroom_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
    );

//Commercial model:

     var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Showroom' => array(
            'className' => 'Showroom',
            'joinTable' => 'commercials_showrooms',
            'foreignKey' => 'showroom_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'commercial_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
    );
```